# Codimensions and infinite dimensional vectorspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is an infinite dimensional vectorspace, and $W \subset V$ is another infinite dimensional subvectorspace. Assume that $V/W$ is finite dimensional. Let $U \subset V$ denote a *finite* dimensional subspace such that $U \cap W = \{ 0 \}$. Does the dimension formula

$\dim V/ ( W \oplus U) = \dim V/W - \dim U$

still hold?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the formula still holds. Let $f:V\to V/W$ be the quotient map. By assumption, $f$ is injective on $U$. Hence, $\dim f(U)=\dim U$. Taking the quotient of $V/W$ by $f(U)$ results in the space of dimension $\dim(V/W)-\dim(U)$. On the other hand, this quotient is naturally isomorphic to $V/(W\oplus U)$.